# Checking if an M2M field is empty or not in Django

Tags: django

I have the following models:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
    has_toppings = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def check_if_there_are_toppings(self):
         if len(self.toppings.all()) > 0:
             self.has_toppings = True

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Pizza.toppings.through)
def toppings_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.check_if_there_are_toppings()
    instance.save()
```

What I want to do is update the `has_toppings` field whenever the `toppings` length is more than 0. What would be the correct way to do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why not annotate the `Pizza` queryset when you need to know if there are toppings, this looks like a "safer" option. Since an m2m can be changed by all sorts of triggers (like removing a `Topping` object itself, another program that talks to the database, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is probably *not* a good idea to do that. There can be a lot of reasons how a many-to-many relation changes. It will be very hard, or even impossible to cover all of these. For example a `Topping` object itself can be removed, and therefore trigger a change in all the many-to-many relations where the topping was used. Furthermore the Django ORM has some functions like [**`.bulk_create(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) and [**`.update(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) that circumvent Django's signal mechanism, and thus can render the database in an inconsistent state. Therefore it might make more sense to just remove the `has_toppings` field:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
    # no has_toppings
```

It might make more sense to just annotate your `Pizza` querysets. For example with:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Pizza.objects.annotate(
    has_toppings=Exists(
        Pizza.toppings.through.objects.filter(pizza_id=OuterRef('pk'))
    )
)
```

This will generate a query that looks like:

```
SELECT pizza.id,
       EXISTS(
           SELECT U0.id, U0.pizza_id, U0.topping_id
           FROM pizza_toppings U0
           WHERE U0.pizza_id = pizza.id
       ) AS has_toppings
FROM pizza
```

You can use this queryset when you access `Pizza.objects`, by setting a manager:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

class PizzaManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Pizza.objects.annotate(
            has_toppings=Exists(
                Pizza.toppings.through.objects.filter(pizza_id=OuterRef('pk'))
            )
        )

class Topping(models.Model):
    pass

class Pizza(models.Model):
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
    objects = PizzaManager()
```

So we can now for example retrieve all `Pizza`s with toppings with:

```
Pizza.objects.filter(has_toppings=True)
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about the annotation. Where would I put the code and how would I update the Pizza object?

Comment: @darkhorse: you don't update the `Pizza` object. You simply, when you need `Pizza` object(s), query and let the annotation fill in an extra field. So the `Pizza` object has *no* `has_toppings` field.

Comment: Ok that is definitely an interesting approach, but one that will solve my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can to it simply checking count of the toppings, by calling:

```
is_empty = instance.toppings.all().count() == 0
```

`is_empty` would have `False` if there are more than 0 toppings, and `True` if there are no toppings.

Hope, it helps.